# Bisection Recursion not working as expected (Python)

Tags: python

I have identified an interval to work with (from a graph plotted in Python) - my interval being [4, 6]. I have written a program (not fully complete) so that 1) I take the midpoint of the interval (leftintervalwall, rightintervalwall) and see if it gives me 0 as an output. 2) If not, that midpoint, now becomes the new leftintervalwall (rightinterval wall remains the same).

I have updated my code: however, when I calculate the output of my function when the root is found, i get a value of 1.014 which cannot be correct. It should be close to 0. So I am not sure where the holes are in my code. Many thanks!

```
def continousfunction(xpoint):
    output = float(np.power(xpoint, 2) - np.log1p(1 + xpoint) - 30)
    return output;


                        
def processinterval(a, b):
    
        intervalmidpoint = (a + b) / 2
        return intervalmidpoint;
        

   
def findroot(a, b, accuracy):
    if(continousfunction(a) < 0 and continousfunction(b) > 0):
        bisection(a, b, accuracy)
        

        
def bisection(a, b, accuracy):
        
            
                intervalmidpoint = processinterval(a,b)
            
                if(continousfunction(intervalmidpoint) < 0):
                    a = intervalmidpoint
                    return bisection(intervalmidpoint, b, accuracy)
                    
                    
                
                print(continousfunction(intervalmidpoint))
   

def main():
    
    
    
    a = 4
    b = 6
    accuracy = 0.002
    findroot(a, b, accuracy)
    
    
main()
```

Comment: `recursivefunction` and `findroot` return None

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you elaborate a little? Not sure where the errors are in my code (or logic). Many thanks.

Comment: mmm... at the moment you can forget about my comment, you just print each result and not storing it, so should be ok. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yeh that was just to see if I could see the correct intervals being printed out. No problem.

Comment: what is the value of `c0`

Comment: that is the midpoint of each interval - which then becomes the new left point of the next interval

Comment: can you print the current intermediary outputs of your program in your problem statement and expected values ?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example on how the bisection method could be implemented. I add an accuracy parameter inorder to avoid recursion error. I did an extra test on another function as well, test1.

[Your recursion print always a the same interval]

```
def bisection(a, b, accuracy=0.002):
    midpoint = (a+b)/2
    f_m = func(midpoint)

    if abs(f_m) < accuracy:
        return midpoint
    
    # same sign
    if func(a) > 0 and f_m > 0 or func(a) < 0 and f_m < 0:
        return bisection(midpoint, b, accuracy=accuracy)
    if func(b) > 0 and f_m > 0 or func(b) < 0 and f_m < 0:
        return bisection(a, midpoint, accuracy=accuracy)
    # opposite sign
    if func(a) > 0 and f_m < 0 or func(a) < 0 and f_m > 0:
        return bisection(a, midpoint, accuracy=accuracy)
    if func(b) > 0 and f_m < 0 or func(b) < 0 and f_m > 0:
        return bisection(midpoint, b, accuracy=accuracy)


# test 1
def func(x):
    return x**3 -x -2

# initial boundaries of the interval
a, b = 1, 2
accuracy = .002

try:
    print(bisection(a, b, accuracy = .002))
except RecursionError:
    print('No root found with that accuracy limit')

# test 2
def func(x):
    return float(np.power(x, 2) - np.log1p(1 + x) - 30)

# initial boundaries of the interval
a, b = 4, 6
accuracy = .002

try:
    print(bisection(a, b, accuracy = .002))
except RecursionError:
    print('No root found with that accuracy limit')
```

Output

```
1.521484375 # for test 1
5.66015625  # for test 2
```

Comment: When I modify my code, I get 5.75 exactly as the root for the test 2 function

Comment: I added the accuracy term as a key parameter to avoid infinite recursions

Comment: I have also added it. I have attachted new code above

Comment: because when i put 5.75 back into the function i get 1.014807 which cant be correct. it should be around 0

Comment: the root should be at around 5 as shown by the my result, here you can have a graphical check https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x**2+-+log%281%2Bx%29+-30 ,  and with 5.6 I get 0.14 something which I guess it looks like a root...I don't know where 5.75 is from

Comment: yes there are many... for example a `rightintervalwall = 6`,  a check which does not care about negative values `calculatefunction2(intervalmidpoint) < accuracy`, and more. I sugget you to look at https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit it is very good made and show you what's going (it does not support `numpy` so try to use the function I have in my solution, `test 1`). try it!

Comment: I have updated my code - but my output gives me 1.014 (when i put in the root) Was wondering if people had any more suggestions on my code.

Comment: @Weightlifting Without Limits please indent properly the code

Comment: `return bisection(intervalmidpoint, b, accuracy)` your recursion does not satisfy the criteria of bisection. You just make "a" closer to "b" by halving the distance.